# Accessing JSON data using Angular 2.0

Tags: angularjs, json

I am fairly new to using JavaScript in relation to Angular 2.0. I have about 2 years of experience with Java, so I'm familiar with programming (in general).

In my application, I have a JSON payload whose data I would like to access. Normally, in Java, I might make a map to capture said data.

**My question**: *How does one capture data in Angular (2.0) to be used within the scope of a controller/service?*

Sample Data:

```
 "impairments":[  
  {  
     "type":"SUCKOUT",
     "lowBin":132000000,
     "highBin":210000000,
     "severity":57
  }
```

In which I am trying to use the data for **"type"**

Thanks so much!

Comment: What is your controller code?

Comment: Hey Niket! It is under copyright, I cannot post it :/ I can tell you that I am working within a HeaderController for the header of the application UI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your JSON data doesn't look correct. Assuming a get request to `/some/endpoint/here` in your app returns:

```
{
    "impairments": [
        {
            "type":"SUCKOUT",
            "lowBin":132000000,
            "highBin":210000000,
            "severity":57
        }
    ]
}
```

You can use a simple controller like:

```
app.controller("yourController", ['$http', '$scope', function($http, $scope) {
    $scope.type = null;
    $http.get('/some/endpoint/here').then(
        function(response) {
            //response.data contains all the response data
            $scope.type = response.data.impairments[0].type;
        },
        function() {
            //error occured, do something
        }
    );
}]);
```

Then in your controller you can simply use:
`{{type}}`

---

**PLEASE NOTE**

For security reasons, angularJS advices to prefix all the JSON response with `)]}',\n` and angular strips it off.

> A [JSON vulnerability](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/20/anatomy-of-a-subtle-json-vulnerability.aspx) allows third party website to turn your JSON
>   resource URL into [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) request under some conditions. To counter this
>   your server can prefix all JSON requests with following string
>   ")]}',\n". Angular will automatically strip the prefix before
>   processing it as JSON.

You can read more at: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#security-considerations

Comment: Thank you! I was looking actually for the understanding of $rootscope (did not know about this before). I realized that the data had already been mapped to some $rootscope variables that I was able to use to solve my issue. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Glad to help you mate :)